# ios 6.1 twitter and facebook settings not show allowed apps

Tags: xcode, facebook, twitter, settings, acaccountstore

i have a big problem with a ios 6.1 simulator. My apps not shows in phone (simulator) settings. See the image above:

[image: Facebook settings]

[image]

The code for request an account allow is correct, on the phisical devices, works:

```
ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
                              ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];


[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                              completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!granted){
         NSLog(@"____TW not granted:%@ ",error.localizedDescription);
     } else {
         NSLog(@"____TW granted");
     }

 }];
```

how can resolve it? i tryed to reinitialize simulator but without effect.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this?

Comment: I am also having this problem on the simulator!

Comment: i have't found the solution yet :(

Comment: Yup.  In the iPhone 6.1 sim, after accepting the facebook alertview, `granted` seems to always return NO.